# Specific if else statement after using a SQL call to retrieve data from a database. Visual Studios 2015 / C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

I'm attempting to add the finishing touch to a project I've been working on and am currently trying to modify a feature that I've created. The feature being that if a student has completed an examination, they are able to view the results. However, what I want to do is create an if else statement that is essentially: if the exam has been taken and completed, then they are redirected to the page that shows them the specific exam's results. Else, it returns a message at the top of the page stating "This examination has not been completed yet."

The current code I have (which is operated through a button on the page) is:

```
protected void btnViewPrevExam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["intExaminationID"] = ddlExamination.SelectedValue; 
        Int32 int32StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["StudentID"]);
        Session["int32StudentID"] = Convert.ToInt32(int32StudentID);

        // Define the ADO.NET connection object.
        SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OPT"].ConnectionString);

        // Develop the SQL call.
        // Develop the SQL call.
        String strSQL = "";
        strSQL = "SELECT AnswerID, Question, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC, OptionD, CorrectAnswer, Answer ";
        strSQL += " FROM Question, Answer, Examination, Student ";
        strSQL += " WHERE Examination.ExaminationID = " + ddlExamination.SelectedValue;
        strSQL += " AND Student.StudentID = " + int32StudentID;
        strSQL += " AND Answer.QuestionID = Question.QuestionID ";
        strSQL += " AND Answer.StudentID = Student.StudentID ";
        strSQL += " AND Examination.ExaminationID = Question.ExaminationID ";
        // Create the SQL command object.
        SqlCommand objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, objSqlConnection);
        // Retrieve the row from the table.
        objSqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader objSqlDataReader = objSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        objSqlDataReader.Read();
        if (strSQL != null)
        {
            objSqlDataReader.Close();
            objSqlConnection.Close();
            Response.Redirect("StudentExamResults.aspx");
        }
        else 
        {
            this.Master.MessageForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            this.Master.Message = "The selected examination has not been completed.";
        }        
    }
```

What this button does currently is that it will send the student to the examination results page regardless if the examination has been completed or not. This is due to the line "if (strSQL != null)" and it never being null because the SQL call has been made and filled. I've attempted other ideas, as well as performing a objSqlDataReader for the AnswerID but it didn't work properly. This is a small extra feature I'd like to add to this project that I thought of and would be very pleased if I could find some help on sorting out what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing if `strSQL` is not `null` will always succeed because you are setting it to a non-`null` value earlier in the method.

To see if a record already exists for a previously-completed examination, you need to check the return value of the call to [`objSqlDataReader.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read); it will return `true` as long as there are additional rows (or, in this case, a first row) to consume from your `SELECT` query.  Thus, change this...

```
objSqlDataReader.Read();
if (strSQL != null)
{
```

...to this...

```
if (objSqlDataReader.Read())
{
```

As an additional note, consider wrapping `objSqlConnection`, `objSqlCommand`, and `objSqlDataReader` in [`using` blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to ensure they are properly closed/disposed.  As it is now, you are not closing `objSqlDataReader` and `objSqlConnection` when the exam needs to be completed, and `objSqlCommand` is not disposed at all.  `objSqlDataReader` would then be closed as follows, regardless of which branch of the `if` is taken...

```
using (SqlDataReader objSqlDataReader = objSqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (objSqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        //objSqlDataReader.Close();// No longer necessary - handled by using
        objSqlConnection.Close();
        Response.Redirect("StudentExamResults.aspx");
    }
    else 
    {
        this.Master.MessageForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        this.Master.Message = "The selected examination has not been completed.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't care about the contents, rather you just want to check if the row exists, you can do something like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(AnswerID) FROM Question ........ WHERE ......";

using (var connection = CreateConnection()) {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)) {
        bool exists = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
        if (exists) {
            Response.Redirect("StudentExamResults.aspx");
        } else {
            // Do the other thing
        }
    }
}
```